# How to multiply each elements of an array with a vector

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, statistics, multiplication

I am new to **R**, and will be asking simple question.

I am multiplying each elements of an array eg. `array[,,]` with `dim` of `10,10,10` with a `vector V` of `1000 length (1 dim)`.

I wanted each elements of the `array[,,]` to be repeated `length(V) times`. I guess the `dim(array[,,]` will change. But `array[,,]*V` doesn't seem to be appropriate way.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear. If it is just a simple multiplication, then do `ar1*v1`

Comment: Ok, let me make it clear, let us say you have three dimensional array, and you want to multiply each element of the array by a vector of 100 elements length say 1 to 100. So each of the three dimensions of the array will have now length of 100.  what about how?

Comment: `array(rep(ar1*v1, v1), dim = c(100, 10, 10)`

Comment: If the resulting object is an array of 10X10X10X1000, you might be looking for `?outer`.

Comment: Thanks, Imo, Akrun. outer was what I was looking for!